# Is OpenStreetMap suitable for me?

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, routing, maps

I'm planning to create a map with GPS and routing support as well as other custom features for my local area. It will be for a commercial usage. I'm okay with showing OpenStreetMap logo in my app.

Is it okay to use OpenStreetMap data as base and add more features on my own for free?

Do I have to host my own server? (It will only support a map with around 4km square feet.)

But I do not wish to make what I created open-sourced.

Is OpenStreetMap for me?

Answer (score 2):

If you intent to create a derivative database then you have to share parts of your work. For more information read the [Legal FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ#3b._If_I_have_data_derived_from_OSM_data.2C_do_I_have_to_distribute_it.3F), especially section 3. And ideally contact your lawyer.

Comment: I've a hard time understanding derivative database. Care to explain a bit with example? Thanks.

Comment: + 1. It is important to note that "share" can mean you release the original data or the created data as odbl. At the end I would recommend you to release any modifications to OSM and e.g. differentiate through your potentially closed source app

Comment: @moeseth No I can't, I'm not a lawyer. I can only point you to the legal FAQ.